# Trying to post data using axios and formData but it's empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, form-data

I'm using Vue3 and axios to post a form using `FormData`, but it's empty, nothing is being passed.

> {"formData":{}}

Here's what I am doing:

```
const formData= new FormData();
formData.set("name", name);

axios.post("postform",  formData);
```

I also tried this:

```
formData.set("name", "John Doe");
axios.post("postform",  formData);
```

and this:

```
formData.append("name", "John Doe");
axios.post("postform",  formData);
```

But no success. There's no errors, it's just empty.

I retrieve them in PHP like this:

```
 echo $request->input("name");
```

**So my question is:**

How do I post data using `FormData`?

Comment: try adding this `print_r($_REQUEST)` in php rather than `echo $request->input("name");
` and see what shows

Comment: Thank you. It's empty. It shows an empty formData array.

Comment: are you using laravel in backend @ThiagoGuimarães?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not sending any file (or your form is not maltipart/form-data) you can use following method to send data through axios:

```
let formData = {};
formData.name =  "John Doe";
axios({
  url: "postform",
  method: "POST",
  data: formData
});
```

EDIT:

If you are sending any files then in my case following worked for me:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("name", "hello world");



axios({
    url: 'postform',
    method: "POST",
    data: formData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to send files.

Comment: @ThiagoGuimarães I have edited the answer please check

Comment: Doesn't work but thank you. It says getHeaders doesn't exist on type formData

Comment: @ThiagoGuimarães i have edited the answer (added `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`) in headers. Try that

Comment: Thank you but I it was actually my fault. I had formData inside `{}` in axios. But I upvoted your answer for taking your time. Thank you once again

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your FormData Object to simple object and then send that object to server.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.set("key1", "value1");
formData.set("key2", "value2");

let data = {};

// convert the key/value pairs
for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
    data[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}

axios.post("postform",  data);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will upvote because I could see the values but I'm still getting some errors when trying to pass the value to the key. `Type 'FormDataEntryValue' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: FormData entry value may be either string, null or File. Try `formData.get('foobar').toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to send the header `'Content-Length': formData.getLengthSync()`. This call works for me:

```
const response = await axios.delete(url, {
  "data": formData,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": formData.getLengthSync()
  }
});
```